# I want to change my code to match the airbnb rules

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import PropType from 'prop-types';
import Counter from '../components/Counter';
import * as counterActions from '../store/modules/counter';

class CounterContainer extends Component {
  handleIncrement = () => {
    console.log('+');
    const { CounterActions } = this.props;
    CounterActions.increment();
  }

  handleDecrement = () => {
    console.log('-');
    const { CounterActions } = this.props;
    CounterActions.decrement();
  }

  render() {
    const { handleIncrement, handleDecrement } = this;
    const { number } = this.props;

    return (
      <Counter
        onIncrement={handleIncrement}
        onDecrement={handleDecrement}
        number={number}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I am using ESLint airbnb.
When I write the above code
ESLint

raise Error an 'CounterActions' is missing in props validation. And 'number' is missing in props validation

so i add

```
CounterContainer.propTypes = {
  number: PropType.number,
  CounterActions: PropType.func,
};
```

propType "number" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration. 
propType "CounterActions" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration.

I do not know how to change it from now on.
I'm trying to apply ESLint while following the tutorial.
How do I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's asking for you to set `defaultProps` since they are both optional. Since it looks like they're both required for this component, set them to `isRequired`:

```
CounterContainer.propTypes = {
  number: PropType.number.isRequired,
  CounterActions: PropType.func.isRequired,
};
```

This will bypass the `react/require-default-props` rule for those props.